# Recursion callback mechanism

Tags: java, recursion, callback

I would like to implement an algorithm to print all valid (e.g., properly opened and closed) combinations of n-pairs of parentheses.

Example:

> input: 2 (e.g., 2 pairs of parentheses) output: ()(), (())

The algorithm works fine:

```
1 public static void f(int l, int r, char[] str, int count) {
2 if (l < 0 || r < l) return; 
3 if (l == 0 && r == 0) {
4     System.out.println(str); 
5 } else {
6     if (l > 0) { 
7         str[count] = ‘(‘;
8         f(l - 1, r, str, count + 1);
9     }
10     if (r > l) { 
11         str[count] = ‘)’;
12         f(l, r - 1, str, count + 1);
13     }
14 }
15 }
```

which I call using f(count, count, str, 0);, let's assume in our example f(2,2,"",0)

**Question:** I am a newbie in programming and I don't understand **the callback mechanism inside the recursion process**.

To detail step by step:

```
f(2,2,"",0)
-> str = "(" -> f(1,2,"(",1)
-> str = "((" -> f(0,2,"((",2)
-> str = "(()" -> f(0,1,"(()",3)
-> str = "(())" -> f(0,0,"(())",4)
-> print "(())" !
```

In this point I am perplexed. So I am going up to the previous call, after calling f(0,0,"(())",4). I get to line 15 inside f(0,1,"(()",3).
**Here is the gap, what happens here?** I should try here to insert "(" (which will fail since l==0), however what do I have in the call stack?

I can get back to the source call if I can understand this. Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You should _not_ try to insert '(' at that point precisely because you have no '(' left. You will traverse back up the call stack until count is `1` again, where you will try to append ')' instead of '('.

Comment: How do you translate in technical details "because you have no '(' left" ?

Comment: You already translated it in the code: `if (l > 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function completes, then it returns to the place where it was originally called.  Therefore, after you reach line 15 of `f(0,1,"(()",3)`, the program will resume at line 13 of `f(0,2,"((",2)`.  If you were to print the parameters at the beginning of each function call, you would get something like this:

```
f(2, 2, "", 0)
  f(1, 2, "(", 1)
    f(0, 2, "((", 2)
      f(0, 1, "(()", 3)
        f(0, 0, "(())", 4)  <-- print "(())"
    f(1, 1, "()", 2)
      f(0, 1, "()(", 3)
        f(0, 0, "()()", 4)  <-- print "()()"
```